# Protobuf Not Working - Jetbrains Rider .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to do a simple gRPC tutorial.  Initial I started with Jetbrains Rider by creating a new gRPC service, then I created a console app for the client and installed:

```
Google.Protobuf - 3.11.4
Grpc.Net.Client - 2.28.0-pre2
Grpc.Tools - 2.28.0-pre3
```

It doesn't look like the generated code for the `greet.proto` is being generated as I am getting red squigglies `var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);`

However, when I open the project in Visual Studio, everything seems to work.  Am I missing a plugin or something here?

My `csproj`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.11.4" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.28.0-pre2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.28.0-pre3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto">
        <GrpcServices>Client</GrpcServices>
        <OutputDir>obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\</OutputDir>
        <Access>Public</Access>
        <ProtoCompile>True</ProtoCompile>
        <ProtoRoot></ProtoRoot>
        <CompileOutputs>True</CompileOutputs>
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </Protobuf>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

if it compiles in Rider (compiled files should be in folder `obj/Debug/[your-netcore-target]/`), then you have it set up correctly and it works (= it compiles). "Only" Rider has trouble to find compiled classes (tested in Rider 2019.3.4 build 193.6494.48).

It seems to be a bug (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-25412 or https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-39721) in Rider which is caused by mixing NuGet versions.

Make sure all other projects within your solution uses the same versions of gRPC related libs.

I managed to set it with these versions (targeting netcoreapp3.0):

My Server app:

```
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.27.0" />
```

My client app

```
<PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.11.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.25.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.27.0">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

**Beware** that Grpc.AspNetCore in version 2.27.0 contains references to Google.Protobuf 3.11.2 and Grpc.Tools 2.27.0. So I cannot use different versions in my client project. Or I can, it will compile but Rider won't find the files.

Simply said make sure that all gRPC related nugets within **all projects** in you solution use the exact same version, **including referenced** nugets (referenced by the nugets you explicitly use).

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the projects obj directory, and reloading the solution.